# Can I use Cordova to access a phone's native camera in a website without creating platform specific apps?

Tags: android, cordova

I am currently working on a website and we are interested in using cordova to access a phone's camera. In the online documentation it seems that you would need to create (for each type of platform) a config file and add the necessary permissions. The question is, can you access a phone's camera without having to create a platform specific app? In other words, can I use the already existing website to access the phone's camera without having to create a platform specific app that has all the camera and storage permissions defined? My assumption is that I would need to create the apps and just have the apps redirect the user to the website. In that way I would have the permissions and then we could just implement the cordova camera api from there.